# Showing text with CGContextShowTextAtPoint draws strange text

Tags: ios, xcode, text, sdk, cgcontext

I'm just trying to overlay a text in a UIImage (using CGContext) but it doesn't show the text I specified. In this code I'm giving as the text argument `"Hello"` but it shows "eÉääc". I don't know what's happening I think the characters are displaced but I don't know how to solve it.
This is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
CGContextSetTextMatrix(c, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0, 0, -1.0, 0, 0));
CGContextSelectFont(c, "ArialMT", 50, kCGEncodingFontSpecific);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(c, 255, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(c, 255, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(c, 2);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(c,100,100, "Hello", 5);
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I'm using the Spanish Keyboard (I don't know if this matters) and the iPad (where I'm testing the application) is in Catalan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGContextShowTextAtPoint()` interprets the given text according to the specified encoding parameter of `CGContextSelectFont`. You have chosen `kCGEncodingFontSpecific`, which is the font built-in encoding (whatever that might be).

The only other choice is `kCGEncodingMacRoman`:

```
CGContextSelectFont(c, "ArialMT", 50, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
```

Then your text should display correctly, as long as you use only characters from the ASCII character set.

For non-ASCII characters, you have to convert the string to the MacRoman encoding, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13743834/1187415 for an example.

Note that `CGContextShowTextAtPoint` *cannot display* general Unicode strings, and even has problems with the Euro (€) character. The  `drawAtPoint:withFont:` method of `NSString` does not have these limitations.